# How to use this function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following jQuery function which is supposed to detect when an element first scrolls into view on a page:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

My mind is mush today... how can I use this function?

Assume I want to detect when `$('.guardrail360')` comes into view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to bind the scroll event and do the detection when that event fires.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  isScrolledIntoView('.guardrail360');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. Just don't use a naive `window.scroll` implementation if you are concerned with user experience and/or performance.

> It's a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll
>   event. Depending upon the browser the scroll event can fire a lot and
>   putting code in the scroll callback will slow down any attempts to
>   scroll the page (not a good idea). Any performance degradation in the
>   scroll handler(s) as a result will only compound the performance of
>   scrolling overall. Instead it's much better to use some form of a
>   timer to check every X milliseconds OR to attach a scroll event and
>   only run your code after a delay (or even after a given number of
>   executions - and then a delay).
>
> -John Resig, creator of jQuery, on [ejohn.org](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)

## Method 1: setInterval

First, there is the naive approach using timers:

```
var $el = $('.guardrail360');

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView($el)) {
        // do stuff

        // to run this block only once, simply uncomment the next line:
        //clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 150);
```

## Method 2: window.scroll event

Then there is the trivial, yet **crazy inefficient way** using the scroll event (depending on the browser, the scroll event will fire hundreds of times per second, so you do NOT want to run a lot of code in here, particularly not code that triggers browser reflows/redraws).

Ever visited a site where scrolling down the page felt sluggish and jittery? That is often caused by a piece of code like this one right here:

```
var $el = $('.guardrail360');

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView($el)) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

## Method 3: best of both worlds

The nifty hybrid approach for high traffic sites, as proposed by John Resig in the [aforementioned blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/):

```
var $el = $('.guardrail360'),
    didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        if (isScrolledIntoView($el)) {
            // do stuff

            // to run this block only once, simply uncomment the next line:
            //clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
}, 250);
```

## Method 4: Throttling / Debouncing

Throttling (minimum N milliseconds between invocations) or debouncing (only one invocation per 'burst') patterns can also be used to efficiently limit the rate at which your inner code executes. Assuming you'd be using [Ben Alman's jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), the code looks like this:

```
var $el = $('.guardrail360');

// Throttling
$(window).on('scroll', $.throttle( 250, function(){
    if (isScrolledIntoView($el)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}));

// Debouncing
$(window).on('scroll', $.debounce( 250, function(){
    if (isScrolledIntoView($el)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}));
```

(Note that debouncing acts slightly differently from the other implementations, but that can sometimes be what you want, depending on your user experience scenario)

Comment: How can I limit a function so that it is only fired once?

Comment: In the hybrid code above, simply assign the timer to a variable (var myTimer = setInterval(...)), then use clearInterval(myTimer) in the 'do stuff' block

Comment: Why would I want a timer (I'm assuming as in seconds, etc.) having anything to do with this function?

Comment: Using a timer makes sure the isScrolledIntoView code only runs 4 times a second (or if you want it to run the check 10 times/sec, set the interval to 100 ms) instead of 50-60 times per second, which can easily make your site run sloooooowly

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isScrolledIntoView('.guardrail360') ) {

}
```

As suggested by the other answers, you should use act upon `$(window).scroll()`. In addition, in order to make the if statement run the first time the element is scrolled into view, I created this `run_once` function for you:

```
$('window').on('scroll', function() {

    if ( isScrolledIntoView('.guardrail360') ) run_once(function() {
            // ...
    });

});

function run_once( callback ) {

    var done = false;

    return function() {

        if ( !done ) {

            done = true;

            return callback.apply( this, arguments );

        }

    };

}
```

Comment: this has to be in scroll event though

Comment: How can I limit the scroll event so that the if statement is only triggered the FIRST time the element is scrolled into view?

Comment: But if the element is, say, a couple of viewports down the page, you are forcing the poor browser to execute the function body dozens if not hundreds of times before finally reaching its goal and setting `done` to `true`. And what happens if the page has 10 'guardrail' elements that need to be watched like this... or 100?

Comment: @JensRoland The function body of `run_once` will run *only* when the element is in view, not as many times as the `.scroll` function body. The function body of `.scroll` is another thing. But you're right about 10 guardrail elements though. :)

Comment: @JensRoland I don't understand the downvote either. How does my answer not help?

Comment: @David: The fact that the window.scroll body, including all the DOM checks, runs with no rate limiting or performance safeguard at all, is an anti-pattern that can and should be avoided in every implementation. I only downvoted to discourage the asker and others from repeating that pattern when there are plenty of perfectly scalable alternative methods.